# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, ORA-00904: "Cash": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I trying to create a trigger like this, but I'm getting error mentioned in the title.

I'm not sure about what is going wrong..

Comment: Replace "Cash" with 'Cash'. String literals are enclosed in single quotes. Only column names are enclosed in double quotes if you are using small case.

Comment: Besides the issue of ticks (single quotes) vs quotes (double) there are other issues. First DUAL does not have a column "DeptName" so each of those selects generates a compile time error. Just use simple assignment statement. Then the major select is going to generate a run time error. It will either give a mutating table exception (ORA-04091) or a too many rows exception (ORA-01422), or no data found (ORA-01403). Unless the Purchases table always has exactly 1 row. None of which are handled. That select doesn't need the Purchases table anyway - at least not as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Validate, how the column `Cash`in the table is defined (if it is defined at all).

While using double quotes in `SELECT` of a column with lower or mixed case, the same quoting must be used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Example

```
create table test
(Cash int);

Select "Cash" from test;

ORA-00904: "Cash": invalid identifier

create table test
("Cash" int);

Select "Cash" from test;
      Cash
----------
         1
```

Comment: Pls make code review. You are joining 3 tables `D, P and E` but only with a predicate between `D and E` - this is the cause of *too many rows*. Here you can profit from learning `ANSI Join` syntax because using it you'd probable omit this error...